# facebook logout code using robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to logout from facebook using robotframework, but not able to succeed. Below is the code I have written. Can anyone please help me out?

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
Login to Facebook
${options}=    Evaluate  
sys.modules['selenium.webdriver.chrome.options'].Options()    sys
Call Method     ${options}    add_argument    --disable-notifications
${driver}=    Create Webdriver    Chrome    options=${options}
Go To     https://facebook.com
maximize browser window
input text  id=email  test123
input text  id=pass  test123
click button  xpath=//input[@data-testid="royal_login_button"]
sleep  10

#Logout code

Wait Until Page Contains Element    xpath=//*[@id="userNavigationLabel"]
click button  xpath=//*[@id='u_w_5']"]  Log out
Close Browser

*** Keywords ***
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, what is the issue/the problem you're facing?

Comment: Hi, Below is the error/issue I am facing.please do the needful. ValueError: 'LOG OUT' modifier does not match to Selenium Keys

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are passing a second argument to `Click Button` - the "Log out" here:

```
click button  xpath=//*[@id='u_w_5']"]  Log out
```

You don't need it, remove it In order to click that xpath.

I can only guess what your ratiaonale was (and I don't want to do that :), but the second argument to that keyword serves a very specific purpose - to simulate a mouse click plus a key, for example "CTRL + click".

Comment: Thank you for the response. I shall try it out and get back to you.